# Need more specific details about policies regarding "review/close votes"

Tags: discussion, support, review-audit, disputed-review-audits

I have reviewed 700+ posts that were flagged to be closed, and I still don't fully understand the concept of what posts should or should not be closed. I have failed two audits in a week.

Here is the first post (supposedly fine, I voted for closing):

[Olympiad of may 2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558827/olympiad-of-may-2015)

Here is the second one (supposedly very bad quality, I voted for leaving open):

[How to prove that there is no positive integer solution to this two variables inequalities system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543679/how-to-prove-that-there-is-no-positive-integer-solution-to-this-two-variables-in)

Frankly, I see no significant difference between the two posts. According to the general consensus of the community, one of them is clearly perfectly fine, and the other one is completely unacceptable. My understanding is that the author should show their work. If that policy is ignored, then I vote for closing the post; unless it is a problem where the very first step requires extreme creativity or the author mentions that hints are appreciated. In that sense, I think the second one is better than the first.

By the way, I don't like the way the results of these audits are presented. The consensus of a community, albeit a strong argument, does not make anything an unquestionable fact. People can be wrong. There is no room for arguments after a failed audit, only a button saying "I understand". What if I don't understand? Or worse, what if I completely disagree?

EDIT:
For those who vote to close this post: please read my comment below. The post suggested by Xander Henderson does not cover the main question I asked.

Comment: Typically, the close queue/reopen queue audits select *any* question with five or more upvotes but no close votes.  Hence, if the vote count goes below +5, and/or if there is a close vote cast on a question, you can take it out of the audit pool.

Comment: See also [Review queue tests in need of revision?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30279/review-queue-tests-in-need-of-revision?rq=1), and [I don't understand this audit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30329/i-dont-understand-this-audit?rq=1).

Comment: Xander Henderson: It only partially does. I would appreciate an answer where more clear guidelines are given. In particular, how should a reviewer interpret the policy regarding the lack of efforts from the author of the post, see the first link. I do not think that I should delete this post on the basis of being a duplicate: the main point is not to call the attenion to these two concrete poor review audits. Nevertheless, thank you for pointing out that other post, I will upload these links there.

Comment: No one here is suggesting that you delete your post, @A.Pongracz.  Many posts remain that are duplicates of other posts.  I see no reason for you to delete your post.  What Xander is indicating is that there is a devoted thread for such requests, for use in the future.

Comment: I understand that. My counterpoint was that it wasn't really the question.